# Could you please solve this question on Bayes theorem without applying bayes theorem?

Tags: bayes-theorem

The contents of 3 urns are: 1 white, 2 red, 3 green balls; 2 white, 1 red, 1 green balls and 4 white, 5 red, 3 green balls. Two balls are drawn at random. These are found to be one white and one green. Find the probability that the balls so drawn came from the third urn.

I have the answer and solution using Bayes theorem. But I would like to know how to solve it without the help  of Bayes theorem, could you please explain the solution and logic.

Comment: What is the selection process? Pick one urn at random, then draw two balls (without replacement)?

Comment: Urn is chosen at random and balls are drawn simultaneously

Comment: What does "Find that the balls so drawn came from the third urn." mean?

Comment: Whatever you are asking, what would it mean to avoid Bayes' Theorem?  Presumably you are asking something about conditional probability and that's all pretty much equivalent to Bayes.

Comment: It is  "Find the probability that the balls so drawn came from the third urn" I have edited the question now

Comment: I would like to solve it without directly applying bayes theorem instead solving it with just basic definitions of probability. So towards the end of the solution we might end up with something similar to bayes theorem formula  and I can get a better understanding of it @lulu

Comment: Bayes' Theorem is more or less equivalent to the definition of conditional probability....Using the one is effectively the same as using the other.  Law of Total Probability gives you the probability that you will observe what you observed.  That's your denominator.  The numerator is then that part of the Total which is explained by the desired condition.

Comment: Suppose instead there is a white urn containing 1 ball marked "1", 2 balls marked "2" and 4 balls marked "3"; a red urn that nobody cares about, and a green urn with 3 balls marked "1", 1 ball marked "2", and 3 balls marked "3". A ball is drawn at random from each of the white and green urns. What is the probability that both will be marked "3"?